# Server auto-installed Decnet during dist-upgrade

Tags: upgrade, updates

When I did a dist-upgrade of my ubuntu 10.04 server, it automatically installed Decnet, and it trew up ncurses based configuration wizard.

I have never heard of Decnet, but I followed the instructions in the wizard, and accepted for it to be installed, and it lead to the disconnection of 2 of my internet uplinks, and the hosted website stopped responding on WAN side. Then I purged Decnet, and rebooted the server, and everything went normal.

So why did my server install Decnet when I did dist-upgrade?

Comment: You don't really say what you were upgrading from, is it to 10.04 or to a point release?

Comment: I was doing `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. It's just installing software package updates.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this issue.

I upgraded from Natty to Oneiric. And during the upgrade I got the ncurse-based configuration wizard, which suggests to skip configuration (which I did). After the next reboot my ethernet based network was broken, too.

I fixed my system like this:

```
# apt-get remove dnet-common libdnet
# rm /etc/init.d/decnet
```

To bring the ethernet up again: (without rebooting)

```
# dhclient3 eth0
```

I assume that an obscure network library which was upgraded caused this. For example `libroar1` depends on `libdnet`. Perhaps some upgraded package started to depend on `dnet-common` in oneiric, when previously it was only recommended - or something like that.